# Oscillating dew point throughout the year?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, climate, humidity

I was searching for the climate of Saudi Arabia and I noticed that the city of Abha (altitude of 7000 feet) has a "strange" behavior in its dew point, as numbeo suggests: https://www.numbeo.com/climate/in/Abha-Saudi-Arabia

What I mean is that the dewpoint oscillates throughout the year.

Does anyone have any idea about why?

Comment: you need to give more details about the weather like wind direction-humidity-air pressure and how this changes during the year.